# Getting Error cannot find -lnl-genl-3, while running make

Tags: 14.04, hostapd

I am trying to install hostapd in ubuntu 14.04. I am getting the below error while running make. Can somebody help me with this ?

```
mafia@mafia-Inspiron-3542:/usr/src/hostap/hostapd$ sudo make
  CC  ../src/drivers/driver_nl80211.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/driver_nl80211_capa.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/driver_nl80211_event.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/driver_nl80211_monitor.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/driver_nl80211_scan.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/netlink.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/linux_ioctl.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/rfkill.c
  CC  ../src/utils/radiotap.c
  CC  ../src/l2_packet/l2_packet_linux.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_md5.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_tls.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_peap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_peap_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_ttls.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_mschapv2.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_gtc.c
  CC  eap_register.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/eap_common.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_methods.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_identity.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/ms_funcs.c
  CC  ../src/eap_common/chap.c
  CC  ../src/eap_server/eap_server_tls_common.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/tls_openssl_ocsp.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/crypto_openssl.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/aes-omac1.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/sha1-prf.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/sha1-tlsprf.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/sha256-prf.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/sha256-tlsprf.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/sha256-kdf.c
  CC  ../src/crypto/random.c
  CC  ../src/ap/wmm.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ap_list.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11.c
  CC  ../src/ap/hw_features.c
  CC  ../src/ap/dfs.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11_ht.c
  CC  ../src/ap/ieee802_11_vht.c
  CC  ../src/drivers/driver_common.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hostapd] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you install the [libnl-genl-3-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-genl-3-dev) package?

Comment: @steeldriver no, I didn't. After installing the package it worked. thanks. Can you please tell me, how to find which package to install for a library ?

Comment: It's partly guesswork; however the `apt-file` utility (available from the `universe` repository) is very useful (you can do stuff like `apt-file search libnl-genl-3` to get the package name). Alternatively, use the online search at packages.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install `libnl-genl-3-dev` - development library and headers for `libnl-genl-3`:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If your library name is say libxyz.so` and it is located on path say:

```
/home/user/myDir
```

then to link it to your program:

```
g++ -L/home/user/myDir -lxyz myprog.cpp -o myprog
```

hope it helped :)